# A-Frame nested plane element not shown correctly

Tags: aframe

I have a a-plane nested in another a-plane.

```html
<a-plane width="10" height="5" color="#FFFFFF">
  <a-plane width="10" color="#000080"></a-plane>
</a-plane>
```

But the result looks like this
[image]
I also tried it with a nested a-image and had the same result. I also tried to remove the inner plane and add it outer and to the same position. But I've got always the same result.

A-Frame Version: 0.9.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've placed two planes in an identical position. The renderer does not know which one should be in front of another (since they are planes and their transforms are identical) - and hence you experience [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting).

You need to position one of the planes so that they won't overlap:

```
<a-plane>
  <a-plane position='0 0 -0.001'>
  </a-plane>
</a-plane>
```